# Why does my flour sifter have cup markings

Tags: measurements, sifting

I have an inexpensive flour sifter that just has wire mesh and a little hand-crank (like one of these [1](http://i.c-b.co/is/image/Crate/HandCrankFlourSifterF13/%24web_zoom%24&/1308302307/hand-crank-flour-sifter.jpg), [2](http://www.bakingishot.com/sites/default/files/images/mrsandersons3cupcranksifter.jpg).)

It has cup markings on the side ("one cup," "two cups").

This is probably a silly question, but why?  Doesn't the flour just start pouring through the wire mesh as soon as you start adding it, thereby making the markings useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a tiny amount of flour will fall through the grating before you start actively sifting; there is a reason there is an agitator and crank to help force the flour through.  I am sure the idea was that you could use the sifter as a measuring cup.

Of course, since most sifters are opaque and the markings are on the outside, it is difficult to get a good measurement.

In practice, these markings are essentially useless, and you are far better off using a proper measuring cup, or even better, a scale.

Personally, I am of the opinion that sifters are hard to clean, not useful for anything else, and in general a pain.  I use a simple sieve when I need to sift.

Comment: In fairness, the cup markings for the two sifters in the links in the original question **do** show on the inside, even though the body of the sifter is opaque. Those circumferential bulges show on both the inside and the outside.